# Rails localization: works for t() but not for ActiveRecord attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, erb

Localization of the Rails3 ERB form for my `user_info` model works for "explanation" but not for "familyname":

```
<%= t("explanation") %>　　　　　　　　　　　　　＃ Works
<%= form_for(@user_info) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :familyname %>                 # Does not work, renders: Familyname
  <%= f.text_field :familyname %>
  <%= f.submit t("update") %>
<% end %>
```

ja.yml in config/locales:

```
ja:
  explanation: ここで説明を書く予定です
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user_info:
        familyname:名字
```

Why would it work for with `t()` but not for ActiveRecord? I double-checked the indentation, I am quite sure I am right doing ja→activerecord→attributes→user_info→familyname

I have another model, really similar, where ActiveRecord attributes are localized with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation looks slightly different than what is given in the [i18n Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models). Please check.

Also, open up the rails console and try this command:

```
I18n.t('activerecord.attributes')
```

This should list all the key/value pair of all the model attribute translations.

Comment: Well spot, thanks! The issue was a missing space, `familyname:名字` does not work but `familyname: 名字` does work :-)

Answer (score 0):

For model attributes, you can use the `human_attribute_for` method

```
User.human_attribute_for :familyname
```